# How to transform SAS String Value into Timestamp?

Tags: sas, timestamp, transform

how to transform this string value into a timestamp format like *dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm*?

```
17.02.22  08:06 (Format dd.mm.yy  hh:mm)
```

This is not working:

```
format BEGINN_TMP DATETIME19.;
BEGINN_TMP = input(BEGINN, DATETIME19.);
```

Comment: What is in the string? Is it `'17.02.22  08:06 (Format dd.mm.yy  hh:mm)'` or just `'17.02.22  08:06'`?  Do you want a datetime value (number of seconds since 1960) or another string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the string's format is not in `datetime.` format. `datetime.` looks as follows:

`22FEB17:08:06:00`

We'll use the `anydtdtm.` informat to read it, which automatically tries a variety of time formats to find the right one.

```
data want;
    string   = '17.02.22  08:06';
    datetime = input(string, anydtdtm.);
    
    format datetime datetime.;
run;
```

Output:

```
string               datetime
17.02.22  08:06      22FEB17:08:06:00
```